# Creating a nested array from a single array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have a search function in my app which gets data from a **fetchedResultsController**. The problem is when I display the filtered data in the **tableView** everytime it gets to a new section, the array starts over and over (due to **indexPath.row** being 0 everytime **indexPath.section** increments). I've never been good at nested arrays and I thought this is the perfect time to learn them, since I can't get over my problem without this array.

So I have this array which is the filtered data out of the **fetchedResultsController**:

```
filteredItems = (fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects?.filter({(budget : Budget) -> Bool in
 return (budget.dataDescription?.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()))!
        }))!
```

How can I make an array called `filteredObjects` which sorts my items for sections? For example

### - Section 1 (  filteredObjects[0] ):

- item 1 (  filteredObjects[0][1] )
- item 2 (  filteredObjects[0][2] )

-

### Section 2 ( filteredObjects[1] ):

- item 1 ( filteredObjects[1][0] )
  etc

Answer (score 1):

Use below method to define number of sections

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
  return filteredObjects.count
}
```

And, for number of rows

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return filteredObjects[section].count
    }
```

And Finally, for CellForRowAtIndexpath

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TaskTableViewCell
    let currentItem = filteredObjects[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

    ... Here, use currentItem as whatever it is (Object or dictionary)

            return cell
}
```

Comment: But how do I create `filteredObjects` out of `filteredItems`, knowing that `filteredItems` is a single array ( `var filteredItems = [Budget]()`)

Comment: What are the parameters/Results of filteredItems? is it array?

Answer (score 0):

```
    let budgets = [Budget]()
    let searchResult = [Budget]()
```

You should always use searchResult array in tableview datasource methods. initially you should add all objects of budgets array to searchResult & load table view.

when search started remove all items from searchResult and add filtered result to search result array & reload tableview.

```
    func search(searchText:String){
        searchResult.removeAll()
        let result = budgets.filter({
            var budget = $0
            let filtered = budget.expenses.filter({
                if let deptName = $0.deptName{
                    return deptName.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
                }
                return false
            })
            budget.expenses = filtered
            return budget.expenses.count != 0
        })

        searchResult.append(contentsOf: result)
    }

struct Budget {
    var expenses = [Expense]()
 }

 struct Expense{
    var deptName:String?
 }
```